# When I load multiple audio files and multiple sets of BirdNET generated selection tables into RavenPro they don't line up. How do i line them up?

Tags: birdnet

When I load multiple audio files and multiple sets of associated BirdNET generated selection tables into RavenPro, they don't line up with each other. Only the first or last audio file and set of selection tables lines up. They line up correctly when I load one audio file and the one associated set of BirdNET generated selection tables into RavenPro. However, I would save a ton of time if I can load (for example) 30 audio files and 30 associated sets of selection tables at once. I have 1,000's to go through to validate true vs. false positives! Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you mind to show a minimalistic screenshot that shows the problem?

Comment: Are the files continuous in time or are there gaps between the files?